# Boolean 1/0 if value is found in multiple columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a df like this one:

```
x1 x2 x3
1  4  1
2  3  1
2  2  4
```

I one to create a new variable called found if the value 1 is present in x1, x2, x3. Expected result:

```
x1 x2 x3 found
1  4  1  1
2  3  1  1
2  2  4  0
```

I´m using tidyverse and mutate, but cannot find how to mutate with multiple columns.

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` :

```
df$found <- +(rowSums(df == 1) > 0)

#  x1 x2 x3 found
#1  1  4  1     1
#2  2  3  1     1
#3  2  2  4     0
```

If you want to use it in `dplyr` pipe :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(found = +(rowSums(. == 1) > 0))
```

---

Some other ways :

```
df$found <- +(apply(df == 1, 1, any))
df$found <- +(Reduce(`|`, lapply(df, `==`, 1)))
```

The `+` at the beginning converts logical values from `TRUE`/`FALSE` to `1`/`0` respectively.